# Map data with fields value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Ive a data set in below format and trying below big query

[image]

Some additional content, Key & value are array format.

Table format: id, {key: "abc", value: "true"} and when I unnest it looks as in above screenshot.

I want to run a SQL query based on key & value :  ex, I want to get only those value if abc = false, def = true

Sample output I'm expecting.

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm making any sense. but this is what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks!

Comment: still not clear about what exactly your data is! can you provide sample of the initial data - before unnesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you shared you could use a [`CASE` expression](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case_expr). The Query below should work fine for you:

```
SELECT
 id,
 key,
 CASE key
   WHEN 'abc' THEN 'FALSE'
   WHEN 'def' THEN 'TRUE'
   ELSE NULL
   END
   AS VALUE
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE key='abc' or key='def'
```

[image]